# Difference between default file paths in pure Java and in Android

Tags: java, android

I’ve a problem with understanding paths in Android. I’m trying to check if file exists. It works fine in pure Java but fails in Android code and I’m giving the path in the same way (it’s just a file name). I know the file exists (in Android) because I’ve checked it by reading from it before calling to `exists()` method of `File` class. I can read the file with no problem but existence check returns false. So my question is: what is the difference between *‘normal’* and *‘android’* Java when it comes to paths?

This problem seems similar to *‘why file.exists() returns false?’* but I’ve done some reading (a lot of it) and didn’t find an answer (to both – how to check if file exists in Android and what’s the difference between paths in pure Java and Java in Android).

Below I’m pasting the code illustrating the case.

This doesn't work in Android:

```
//--------------------------BUTTONS ACTIONS-----------------------------------------------------

public void onSaveButtonClick(View view){
    msg = textInput.getText().toString();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(msg.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zapiasano!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onLoadButtonClick(View view){

    loadedMsg = "";
    String tmp;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((tmp=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            loadedMsg += tmp + "\n";
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textDisplay.setText(loadedMsg);

    //----------------------FILE CHECK---------------------------------------------

    File f = new File(fileName);
    if(f.exists()){
        textDisplay.setText("File exsists");
    } else{
        textDisplay.setText("File doesn't exsists");
    }
}
```

And this works in pure Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "test.file";
    String str = "hello kitty!";
    String loaded = "this should not load";

    //-----------------SAVE------------------------------------------------
    try {
            FileOutputStream fos;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            fos.write(str.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("saved");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileExists.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileExists.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    //------------------LOAD -----------------------------------------------
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        loaded = bufferedReader.readLine();
        isr.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileExists.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileExists.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(loaded);

    //----------------------FILE CHECK---------------------------------------------
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if(file.exists()){
        System.out.println("file exsists");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> saved
>
> hello kitty!
>
> file exsists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is: what is the difference between ‘normal’ and ‘android’ Java when it comes to paths?

Other Java environments assume a certain current working directory. For all intents and purposes, Android does not.

Your Android code assumes that the following three things are related:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
File f = new File(fileName);
```

The first two are related. The third is meaningless. The equivalent line would be:

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
```

In Android, you **always** determine filesystem paths using framework-supplied methods to give you the base directories to work from (`getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, methods on `Environment`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you – this solves both my problems (what is the difference and how to check if file exists).

Answer (score 0):

Both the implementation of `FileOutputStream(filename)` save the file at the location given by the `filename`. So they kind of assume that its actually the absolute path to file.

The difference is the 'reference' they use to get to that path.

Java on your system sees that path with respect to the source location,
so you use the `FileOutputStream(filename)` to save file at //filename and then use `File(filename)` to get that file from `/<reference path>/filename` and you always find the file therere.

Android's `FileOutputStream(filename)` sees that location with respect to the `files/` directory inside your package directory. While its implementation of `File(pathname)` see the path with respect to the root directory.

So, in android, when you write using `FileOutputStream(filename)`, you are writing to a file `/<path to your package directory>/files/filename`, but when you use `File()`, you actually try to access a file at the root ie `/filename`, which, do not really exists.

Instead try:

```
....
File f = new File (YourActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + filename);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, yours answer has been very helpful!